# NetBeans platform - open file from output console

Tags: java, netbeans, output

I would like to open file specified by its path in NetBeans editor (`IOProvider.getDefault().getIO(...);`).

I would like the same functionality as is when some Java/C/C++ or any other programming language prints an Exception. As far as I went for now:

1. Write the output in console (see the example at the end)
2. By using OutputListener resolve what should be printed as hypertext
3. OutputListener.outputLineAction that defines what to do when clicked on hypertext `IOColorPrint.print(InputOutput io, CharSequence text, OutputListener listener, boolean important, Color color)`
4. Open the file on the system when clicking on

An example of error message I need to resolve:

> The export was successful. The exported file can be found in: C:\Users\MY_USER\Desktop\myFile.xml

The problem that I have is that I have to print all the output in one line and the OutputEvent gives me all the line. Is there any way to get only the Highlited text (The path) ?

Answer (score 0):

This call open new console output tab:

```
IOProvider.getDefault().getIO(...)
```

You should take inputStream and use class while(x=is.read()!=n ....

```
IOProvider.getDefault().getIO(...).getInputStream
```

Let me know, if this was usefull.

Comment: I used OutputListener to specify the action I want to do when the user click on the path of file. 

in the outputLineAction method I inserted Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(oe.getLine()));

The problem that "oe.getLine()" return all the line and not only the specific path. For the moment I print the path in a new line (but it doesn't look pretty ;(    ).

Comment: Could you show snapshot of class/send link, I will try it, thanks

Comment: I resolved this issue. please find follow my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Here the Listener :

```
public class HyperlinkToFileOutputListener implements OutputListener {

private final File file;

public HyperlinkToFileOutputListener(File file) {
    this.file = file;
}

@Override
public void outputLineSelected(OutputEvent oe) {
}

@Override
public void outputLineAction(OutputEvent oe) {
    try {
        if (file.exists()) {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
    }

}

@Override
public void outputLineCleared(OutputEvent oe) {
}
```

}

here the call

```
IOColorPrint.print(io, file.getName(), new HyperlinkToFileOutputListener(file), true, Color.BLUE);
```

best regards